# Hugo generated site is not deploying correctly, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: markdown, hugo, ipfs

I am new to Hugo, studied the platform and created my website.

It all works good in local with the command `hugo server`

When I upload my repository to [fleek hosting](https://blog.fleek.co/posts/go-with-hugo-and-fleek), the site does not render correctly, see it [here](https://mute-violet-7769.on.fleek.co/)

I have tried rewatching all the turorials and I can't seem to find what I am doing differently from others.

You can see the repository here: https://github.com/SequoiaB/SequoiaDocs_Hugo

Could it be the config file?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The integrity check on your CSS fails. That might bring you closer to solving this mystery.